# Кнопки html на python CGI

Tags: html, python, button, cgi, submit

Прошу помощи. При нажатии на кнопку с названием "BUTTON"(условно), выполняется запись значения 1 в переменную A. При этом не таким образом, как submit, перебрасывая на новую, чистую страницу

Comment: Сервер и клиент - это два совершенно разных мира, которые ничего не знают друг и друге, но могут обмениваться сообщениями. На клиенте сущетсвует HTML+CSS+JavaScript. Первые два требуют обязательную перезагрузку страницы - не обязательно новую и чистую, можно ту же самую. В фоне умеет работать только JavaScript и придется писать запрос к питону на нем.

Comment: Поэтому тут три вопроса: 1. устроит ли вас просто переход на ту же страницу. 2. если нет, то знаете ли вы JavaScript, чтобы написать на нем Ajax запрос. 3. Почему именно низкоуровневый CGI, а не Django?

Comment: 1.Вполне устроит, если та самая информация переданная через тот-же submit сохранится. 2. Есть минимальные знания. 3. Джанго имеет слишком много ненужных мне функций - панель администратора, например

Comment: Тогда просто можно указать ту же страницу в форме html, оставив поле action у form пустым в HTML: `<form method="post"> ... </form>`. Можно оставить `method="get"` и парсить запрос. Можно оставить `method="post"` и парсить тело.

Comment: Если нужно фоном, то можно на простом примере посмотреть, как делается запрос Ajax+JQuery на языке JavaScript.